# re-registring jquery.Ui draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I create some elements on runtime (js)
and make them draggable:

```
function fillAttachmentsPerPage(pageNum) {
    createAjaxRequest("Manager/GetAttachments", {
        'locationId': current_folder.attr('id'),
    }).done(function (res) {

        for (var i = 0; i < res.Attachments.length; i++) {

            attachmentDiv = '<div class=\"attachmentDiv ui-draggable\" id="'+ res.Attachments[i].AttachmentId +'" onmouseover=\"attachmentDiv_hover(this);\"'+
            'onmouseout=\"attachmentDiv_onmouseout(this);\">' +
'</div>​';

        }



         $( ".attachmentDiv" ).draggable({
        //    start: function(event, ui) { ... }
            revert: 'invalid',
            drag: function(event, ui) { console.log("dragging") }
        });


        $('a:has(ins)').droppable({
           drop: function(event, ui) {
           console.log($(this).parent())
           setCurrentAttachment(ui.draggable.attr("id"));
           UpdateAttachmentLocation(ui.draggable.attr("id"), $(this).parent().attr("id"))

          }
        });

    });
}


 $( ".attachmentDiv" ).draggable({
//    start: function(event, ui) { ... }
    revert: 'invalid',
    drag: function(event, ui) { console.log("dragging") }
});
```

It works great.

After I drop this element in on dragable element

I create the same elements again, but without the one dropped.

The above registration code is executed again, but yet the elements are not draggable.

Any idea why?

Comment: We'll need to see more. It the new items you added match that selector, and that code is run after they are created, then they will become draggable. So there is more to this story. Can you provide a link or setup a fiddle?

Comment: I always encounter difficulty hosting my js to jsfiddle. Where can I host easily and for free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the elements are being added once the page has loaded, you might need to use the jQuery `.on` method. However, I don't believe the `.draggable` method works with `.on`.

A way of getting around this is to extend jQuery using the code below:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.liveDraggable = function(opts) {
        this.on("mousemove", function() {
            $(this).draggable(opts);
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

You need to add it after you've loaded jQuery, but before you try and use it in your code. Then rather than using:

```
$(".attachmentDiv").draggable
```

You use:

```
$(".attachmentDiv").liveDraggable
```